# Loop over all months in chrono

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I need iterate all months in a code:

```
for (auto m = std::chrono::January; m <= std::chrono::December; m++)
  std::cout << std::format(std::locale { "pt_BR.UTF-8" }, "{:L%B}\n", m);
```

But it happens it's a infinity loop, because the `std::chrono::month` increment has a modulo 12 + 1 behavior. So when the loop `m` variable reaches `December` (12), it wraps around to `January` (1).

I tried with `std::views::iota`:

```
for (auto m : std::views::iota(std::chrono::January) | std::views::take(12))
  std::cout << std::format(std::locale { "pt_BR.UTF-8" }, "{:L%B}\n", m);
```

But fails to compile as `std::chrono::month` don't satisfies the concept `std::weakly_incrementable`.

Comment: `do { } while (m++ <= std::chrono::December)`?

Comment: That's wraps around too :( `m` never get's big than `December`

Comment: Actually, that should be `m++ < std::chrono::December`.

Comment: Maybe `do { } while (++m != std::chrono::January)` Mod arithmetic is fun

Comment: The original attempt didn't work which made me upset because it was intuitive to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your can use a unsigned loop!

```
for (unsigned i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
  std::cout << std::format(std::locale { "pt_BR.UTF-8" }, "{:L%B}\n", 
                           std::chrono::month { i });
```

If you get fancy you can define `std::incrementable_traits` for `std::chrono::month` to work with `std::views::iota`:

```
namespace std {
  template <>
  struct incrementable_traits<std::chrono::month> 
    : incrementable_traits<unsigned> {};
}

for (auto m : std::views::iota(std::chrono::January) | std::views::take(12))
  std::cout << std::format(std::locale { "pt_BR.UTF-8" }, "{:L%B}\n", m);
```

Comment: +1:  Your `do {} while` example is what I've sometimes used: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/cc4685a21e4a4fdae707ad1233c61bbaff241f93/test/date_test/year_month_day.pass.cpp#L138-L156

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for-range loop.

I've de-templatized my `from_to` (inclusive) to make it easier to see the logic.  Similar to Boost [**irange**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html).

(I also have `from_til` (normal half-open range), `after_to` (uncommon half-open range), and `after_til` (uncommon betwixt-only range).)

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace {

struct from_to {
    bool done{ false };
    std::chrono::month hot;
    std::chrono::month last;
    from_to(std::chrono::month first, std::chrono::month last_) : hot{first}, last{last_} {}
    auto operator*() const -> std::chrono::month { return hot; }
    bool operator!=(from_to const&) const { return not done; }
    void operator++() {
        if (done) throw std::logic_error("increment past end");
        if (hot == last) done = true;
        else ++hot;
    }
    auto begin() const -> from_to const& { return *this; }
    auto end() const -> from_to const& { return *this; }
};

auto to_cstr(std::chrono::month m) -> char const* {
    switch (m.operator unsigned()) {
#define CASE(x) case std::chrono::x.operator unsigned(): return #x
        CASE(January);
        CASE(February);
        CASE(March);
        CASE(April);
        CASE(May);
        CASE(June);
        CASE(July);
        CASE(August);
        CASE(September);
        CASE(October);
        CASE(November);
        CASE(December);
#undef CASE
    }
    return "std::chrono::month error";
}

} // anon

int main() {
    for (auto m : from_to{std::chrono::January, std::chrono::December}) {
        std::cout << to_cstr(m) << "\n";
    }
}
```